# Weaker condition for $\mathcal{F}(f\cdot g)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(g)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and

$$\mathcal{F}(f):=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int e^{i\langle x,y\rangle}f(y)dy$$

is the Fourriertransform.

Then we have $\mathcal{F}(f\cdot g)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(g)$.

But what if only $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
$fg \in L^{1}\cap L^2$?

If $g\in L^2$ we define $\mathcal{F}g:=L^2\text{-}\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{F}\chi_{B_R(0)} g$.

Comment: Do you know the $L^2$ and distributional definitions of Fourier transform? Or are you asking specifically about the $L^1$ definition?

Comment: I mean is $\mathcal{F}(fg)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\mathcal{F}(g)*\mathcal{F}(g)$ valid if $fg\in L^1\cap L^2$?

Comment: If you just define the Fourier transform for $L^1$ function, as mentioned in your post, then just to write $\mathcal F(g)$ and $\mathcal F(f)$, you already need both functions to be in $L^1$ ... If you allow for distributions, then the class is much larger than that

Comment: @LL3.14 Thank you. I edited the post. If you know a more suitable and tractable definition you can also use that one.